# Spf dkim edit dns zone mailing issue

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, dkim

I am running an **hosting company** and i was previously affliate of hostgator.
when i sent mails from my domain to my customers 
it would come as info@example.com via hostgator.com and mailed by hostgator.com

But now i switch to the new host
I want to send bulk emails to my optins subscribers of around 452 mails at a click from my other vps and other sitenew@example.com

What i have done is 
enable spf and dkim for the domain where the script is installed

i read over here that i need to add entries to allow 3rd party send mails from my server

what i do is have vps with cpanel centos 32bit os in it

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way to allow for other mail servers to send on your behalf is lookup their ipv4 or ipv6 address and add that to your SPF line in DNS. for example if the mail server for mailserver.domain.com is 1.2.3.4 add "ip4:1.2.3.4/32" to the SPF record.